# Process check if it is one or the other

Tags: c#, process

So I'm a little stuck I know what I want it to do but not sure how to do it?

I need my C# program to check which is relevant.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("Something.exe");
        {
            else
            {
                Process.Start("Somethingelse.exe");
            }
        }
        Close();
    }
```

How would I do a simple check for it whether it's one or the other?

Comment: What are your conditions for starting either process??

Comment: `Process.Start("Something.exe || Somethingelse.exe");` if `Something.exe` failed, start `Somethingelse.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a conditional statement

```
bool bStartSomething = false; // Your condition flag

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bStartSomething == true)
    {
        Process.Start("Something.exe");
    }
    else
    {
        Process.Start("Somethingelse.exe");
    }

    this.Close(); // Close GUI
}
```

if you need to check if the process exists, you can try

```
// Leave off the .exe when using the process name
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Something").FirstOrDefault(); 

if (process != null)
{
    process.Start();
}
```

Comment: The close part is to close the main GUI after opening said process

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense

Comment: @AlanVanderKnight are you trying to start one of the processes based on something else in your code, or just trying to start process `Something.exe` first, and `Somethingelse.exe` if `Something.exe` fails to start?

Comment: Just want it to check which exe is true and then start the correct exe

Comment: So you need to check if `Something.exe` and `Somethingelse.exe` are valid processes and start whichever is valid? Or the first that is valid?